# Solving run-time problems with QT threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, race-condition

My current problem is with two QT threads. One of them emits a signal for starting an operation in the second thread, and afterwards wait for the result. As soon as the second thread finishes, the first thread should continue with its own operation using results from the second thread.

For letting the first thread sleep I use a QMutex and a QWaitCondition. The first thread emits a signal, and afterwards sleeps at the wait condition. But the problem is now: If the second thread somehow managed to be faster than the first thread, and emits the wakeAll()-call before the first thread enters the wait-condition, I get stuck. I could implement a waiting time, but then I am unflexible again, and if the second threads needs more time than the first thread is waiting, I have a problem again.

This problem has already been addressed here: http://woboq.com/blog/qwaitcondition-solving-unavoidable-race.html, but they decided to leave this problem unsolved. So, is there a possibility to avoid this race-condition?

Addition: I don't want to convert this function into a function of the first thread, because this specific function should be accessable from several threads at once without leading to a race condition. I.e. Thread1 should call the function in Thread2, wait til it is finished, Thread3 also wants to call the function, but is not allowed to do that, it has to wait till finish, too. If the function has finished, Thread3 can access it. (Same goes for more than only two threads).

Example function:
This function should emit the signal and afterwards wait for the wake signal:

```
void Spectrometer_Control::moveStepper(int steps, bool dir)
{
    emit stepperMoving();
    qDebug() << "From Spectrometer_Control: Stepper should move in direction " + QString::number(dir) + " from position " + QString::number(MonoPos);
    int newTarget = MonoPos + ((dir == true)?(steps):(-1 * steps));
    qDebug() << "New target: " + QString::number(newTarget);
    emit moveStepperToTarget(steps, dir);
    qDebug() << "Locking WaitMutex!";
    WaitMutex->lock();
    qDebug() << "Waiting for signal!";
    WaitForEngine->wait(WaitMutex);
    WaitMutex->unlock();
    qDebug() << "Finally unlocked!";
}
```

And this function receives the call, and should wake every waiting function up:

```
void Stepper_Control_Worker::moveStepper(int steps, bool dir)
{
    waitMutex->lock();
    qDebug() << "Motor moved from down below!";
    Stepper_Control_Worker::STP[1]->setValue((dir == true)?BlackLib::high:BlackLib::low);
    usleep(50000);
    Stepper_Control_Worker::STP[0]->setValue(BlackLib::low);
    usleep(50000);
    for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        Stepper_Control_Worker::STP[0]->setValue(BlackLib::high);
        usleep(50000);
        Stepper_Control_Worker::STP[0]->setValue(BlackLib::low);
    }
    WaitCond->wakeAll();
    waitMutex->unlock();
    emit StepperMoved(steps, dir);
}
```

The second function is a sub-member (not directly, but can only accessed via) of the class "stepper_control". The stepper-controller outer controls can be used by several functions, not only the function moveStepper from Spectrometer_Control, but for making things easier I only added one external function. But after I don't want to get my stepper confused, I wanted to restrict the access as described above.

Comment: Why use a second thread, if you're just going to put the first thread to sleep and wait for the 2nd to finish?

Comment: Because my second thread is in another class, and should be accessed via several other ways, too. Putting it into a function of this class would make it impossible to use it from other functions in other threads, which also have to wait for it, too. (AFAIK, is that wrong)?

Comment: Threads do not reside in classes. A QThread is more like a thread controller. Classes derived from QObject can be moved to different threads. Regardless of this, I still don't see why you need to create a 2nd thread. Threads allow for concurrent processing, which (according to your description) your application is not making use of this. If you post example code of the problem, you would likely receive better responses and the lack of this may be why someone (not me) has decided to downvote your question.

Comment: @Merlin069: Should this code be complete and runnable?

Comment: Ideally yes, but if not, as long as it is a minimal example that describes the problem clearly, it may be ok. It sounds like your problem is more of a design issue with communication between classes than anything to do with threading.

Comment: @Merlin069: Added some code, I hope that is already enough. I did not add all the wires between these functions. Are they neccessary?

Comment: " I don't want to convert this function into a function of the first thread," - which function are you referring to here?

Comment: @Merlin069: Explanation added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably safe to let the second thread send a signal back and move the code post wait to that slot.

```
class Worker1: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

    //...

    signals:
        void startWorking();
    slots:
        void answer(QVariant);
};

class Worker2: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

    //...

    slots:
        void startWorking();
    signals:
        void answer(QVariant);
};
```

Otherwise you need to have a variable that the second thread sets while holding the `QMutex` to signal the first:

thread1:

```
emit startWorking();
{
    QMutexLocker lock(&thread2->mutex);
    while(!thread2->finished){//loop guards against spurious wakeups
        thread2->cond->wait(&mutex);
    }
}
```

and thread2:

```
{
    QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
    finished=true;
    cond->wakeAll();
}
```

That way if thread2 is faster then `thread2->finished` is already true by the time thread1 arrives and the mutex protects the variable between testing it and waiting on the `QWaitCondition`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` is what you need?

> a blocking queued connection is like a queued connection, but the sender thread blocks until the event is picked up by the event loop of the thread the receiver is living in, the slot is invoked, and it returns;